# Number to decimal part

Tags: php

How can format a int number 10 or 50 or 90 to decimal part 0.10, 0.50 and 0.90 ?

This will be for currency 10 is 0.10 cents and 100 will be 1.00 euro.

Thanks

Comment: What math will get 0.50 from 50?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$number = 100;
echo sprintf("%.2f" . ((float)$number/100 >= 1 ? " euro" : " cents"), (float)$number/100);
```

Output:

```
1.00 euro
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$number = 1234.56;

$number_format = number_format($number, 1);
```

http://php.net/number_format

The code above should give you:

```
1234.5
```

Comment: It will also group whole numbers by thousands and round, not truncate. So the output would actually be `1,234.6`. http://codepad.viper-7.com/Stavq3